# Invoking a SOAP web service: the request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap

I'm trying to invoke a SOAP web service from a .NET application. The web services uses HTTPS (I got that from the URL inside the WSDL) but I can't figure out whether I should invoke it with TLS or SSL. Here's my code:

```
try
{
    string soap = "<BigXmlSOAPHeader></BigXmlSOAPHeader>"
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ws_uri);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
    {
        return true;
    };
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soap);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.Timeout = 1000000000;
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); // it fails here
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  DoSomethingWithException(ex);
}
```

The Exception message is `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

When I copied my header (from debugging) and used it in SoapUI to invoke the web service, it worked which means there's no problem with the web service itself.

UPDATE:
I restarted my application pool in IIS when this occured and it solved the problem. I can't find a logical explanation to this...

Please help.

Comment: Hello, I've the same issue. You call the service from an http connection?

Comment: @Matteo1010 no the URL is HTTPS

Comment: I think my problem is because my web application is http but the 3rd part service is over https. I read is necessary to install a certificate on the  the iss. If I can try this and work I write here

Comment: I don't think your app needs to be HTTPS to invoke an HTTPS web service, I think there's trick when sending the request.

Comment: Thanks I look on the web for the trick. Hope to help you when I find it.

Comment: What's the reason for overloading `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`?

Comment: @NateBarbettini trying to avoid the exception above by ignoring security certificate

Comment: @Fourat What version of .NET Framework are you using? Also, what OS are you running this code on?

Comment: @NateBarbettini .NET 4.5.1 / Windows 10 Pro x64 / Visual Studio Enterprise 2015